# extract rows with conditions and with new created column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data like this

```
id  name  sub  marks
1    a     m    52
1    a     s    69
1    a     p    63
2    b     m    36
2    b     s    52
2    b     p    56
3    c     m    85
3    c     s    62
3    c     p    56
```

And I want output table which contain columns such as id, name and new column result(using criteria if marks in all subject is greater than 40 then this student is pass)

```
id  name  result
1    a    pass
2    b    fail 
3    c    pass
```

I would like to do this in python.

Comment: Can you also share what you have tried so far? Where is your solution not working? We can then be able to help you.

Comment: Pandas, I'm assuming?

Answer (score 2):

Create a boolean mask from `marks`, and then use `groupby` (on `id` and `name`) + `all`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

v = df.assign(result=df.marks.gt(40))\
      .groupby(['id', 'name'])\
      .result\
      .all()\
      .reset_index()
v['result'] = np.where(v['result'], 'pass', 'fail')
```

```
v
   id name result
0   1    a   pass
1   2    b   fail
2   3    c   pass
```

Comment: May I have you help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49133313/pandas-dataframe-select-all-users-rows-if-any-of-his-rows-contains-certain-va/49133512#49133512

Comment: @Wen Absolutely, happy to help.

Comment: Man , Thank you :-)

Comment: @Wen No problem. Actually, I will also need your help here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49119347/how-do-you-remove-rows-with-non-u-s-state-data/49119403#49119403

Comment: Those donwvote is coming from everywhere recent days .. sign ...and no reason left...

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way

```
In [127]: df.groupby(['id', 'name']).marks.agg(
             lambda x: 'pass' if x.ge(40).all() else 'fail'
            ).reset_index(name='result')
Out[127]:
   id name result
0   1    a   pass
1   2    b   fail
2   3    c   pass
```

Another way, inspired from jpp's solution, use `replace` or `map`

```
In [132]: df.groupby(['id', 'name']).marks.min().ge(40).replace(
           {True: 'pass', False: 'fail'}
          ).reset_index(name='result')
Out[132]:
   id name result
0   1    a   pass
1   2    b   fail
2   3    c   pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way via `pandas`. Note your criteria is equivalent to the minimum mark being above 40. This algorithm is computationally more efficient.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

df = df.groupby(['id', 'name'])['marks'].apply(min).reset_index()
df['result'] = np.where(df['marks'] > 40, 'pass', 'fail')

df = df[['id', 'name', 'result']]
```

**Result**

```
   id name result
0   1    a   pass
1   2    b   fail
2   3    c   pass
```

**Explanation**

- First perform a `groupby.min()` by `id` and `name`.
- Then assign the column a string depending on value.