# Pandas dataframe - select all user's rows if any of his rows contains certain value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with patients, date, medications, and diagnosis.
Each patient has a unique id ('pid'), and may or may not be treated with different drugs.

What is best practice to select all patients that at some point have been treated with a certain drug?
Since my dataset is so huge, for-loops and if-statement is the last resort.

Example:

```
IN:
pid drug
1   A
1   B
1   C
2   A
2   C
2   E
3   B
3   C
3   D
4   D
4   E
4   F
```

Select all patient who has at some point been treated with drug 'B'. Note that all entries of that patient must to be included, meaning not just treatments with drug B, but *all* treatments:

```
OUT:
1   A
1   B
1   C
3   B
3   C
3   D
```

My current solution:
1) Get all pid for rows that includes drug 'B'
2) Get all rows that include pid from step 1.
Problem with this solution is that I need to make a loooong if-statement with all pid's (millions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
s = df.groupby('drug')['pid'].apply(set)

result = df[df['pid'].isin(s['B'])]

#    pid drug
# 0    1    A
# 1    1    B
# 2    1    C
# 6    3    B
# 7    3    C
# 8    3    D
```

**Explanation**

- Create a mapping series `s` as a separate initial step so that it
  does not need recalculating for each result.
- For the comparisons, use `set` for O(1) complexity lookup.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest method involves `groupby` + `transform`:

```
df[df.drug.eq('B').groupby(df.pid).transform('any')]

   pid drug
0    1    A
1    1    B
2    1    C
6    3    B
7    3    C
8    3    D
```

In pursuit of a faster solution, call `groupby` on `df`, not a Series:

```
df[~df.groupby('pid').drug.transform(lambda x: x.eq('B').any())]

    pid drug
3     2    A
4     2    C
5     2    E
9     4    D
10    4    E
11    4    F
```

Answer (score 4):

I do support [COLDSPEED](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49133346/1562285)'s answer, but If you say

> ```
> My current solution:
> 1) Get all pid for rows that includes drug 'B'
> 2) Get all rows that include pid from step 1.
> Problem with this solution is that I need to make a loooong if-statement with all pid's (millions)
> ```

can be solved a lot simpler than hardcoding the if's

```
patients_B = df.loc[df['drug'] == 'B', 'pid]
```

or

```
patients_B = set(df.loc[df['drug'] == 'B', 'pid])
```

and then

```
result = df[df['pid'].isin(patients_B)]
```

Comment: Thanks! I think your solution is the same as the solution by @jpp and the best ones. Thank you! :)

Comment: @COLDSPEED Yes. The code in your suggestion gave me around 75s to run, while the other suggestions was around 4s.

Comment: @AnonX Can you please time my latest solution and let me know how it compares to my first?

Comment: @COLDSPEED I made a test on df with 2.6M rows, 4 cols. First solution: 2 minutes to complete. Second solution: 5 seconds to complete. I wonder if it's more the conditioning of the Series, rather than just the Series vs DataFrame. Do you know?

Comment: @AnonX It's an interesting question - one I'm not yet equipped to answer :) But thanks for your patience, I've learned something from this myself.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC `filter`

```
df.groupby('pid').filter(lambda x : (x['drug']=='B').any())
Out[18]: 
   pid drug
0    1    A
1    1    B
2    1    C
6    3    B
7    3    C
8    3    D
```

Comment: If you downvote , the reason is important to me , thank you

Comment: I did not downvote you. Thanks for the reply! It works too! :)